# Ios: UIButton color change automatically with time duration

Tags: ios

I'm a new iPhone programmer. I want to know how to change the UIButton color automatically with a particular time interval.

With Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this helpful, this snippet picks a color at `random` every 3.5 seconds and animates the `backgroundColor` from what ever it currently is to the new one.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{       
[super viewDidLoad];

    NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.5
                                target: self
                                selector: @selector (updateBackgroundColor)
                                userInfo: nil
                                repeats: YES]];

}
- (void) updateBackgroundColor {

    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];

    CGFloat redLevel    = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat greenLevel  = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat blueLevel   = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;

    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: redLevel
                                                green: greenLevel
                                                 blue: blueLevel
                                                alpha: 1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: [self setBackgroundColorTimer: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0     --->this line the code was crashed..... error shows setBackgroundColorTimer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b159b0' like that

Comment: @rajeshkumar Sorry about that, try the edited code in my answer.

Comment: @rajeshkumar Also keep in mind that modifying the timers interval will mean that you will have to adjust "[UIView setAnimationDuration: 3.0];
" to match it.

Comment: There is no Error but not getting proper output MDT